# how to hide access token from api request?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am using angular 2 and sending requests to graph API , and i pass my access token in the request URL , any away to hash it so if someone check network calls will not be able to use it ? and how bad it will be if someone took the app access token and used it ?

Comment: You should never include the app access token in any code that the user access. With the App Access Token someone can do a bunch of bad stuff

Comment: this._http.get(`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/${pageId}?fields=fan_count,name&access_token=${this.access_token}`
  ).map((res: Response) => res.json());

but when i want to send this request for example , i must include access token and if anyone open network and check the calls will be able to read it from the url request , what should i do to prevent this?

Comment: Use a user access token from the specific user that at looking at your page. Or do the request from the server using an app access token

Comment: the thing is , i am doing a page with text input , the user must login with normal account not with fb so he has no access token , after user login he must write his facebook page url in the text input and get details about it . in this case i have no choice but using my own access token . 
and i cant make the request from the server for other reasons , i must handle everything only from front-end . 
any suggestions ?

Comment: Then it is not possible.